# Где прописать ARDUINO_SDK_PATH в CLion?

Tags: c, плагин, arduino, cmake, clion

Установил плагин Arduino на CLion. CMake ругается на ARDUINO_SDK_PATH. Где его прописать и как правильно указать путь?

Comment: а это не переменная среды?

Comment: @YuriiManziuk - настройках винды указал